# Partial view as modal window

Tags: asp.net-mvc, modal-dialog, asp.net-mvc-partialview

My question is simple: is it possible to make a partial view work like a modal window?

Note: In user interface design, a modal window is a child window that requires users to interact with it before they can return to operating the parent application. (source: [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window))

[image]

So, is it possible to make a partial view work like a modal window?

Answer (score 0):

Use following plugin: https://github.com/kylefox/jquery-modal

Razor:

```
// partial view link
@Html.ActionLink("Link", "your_action", "your_controller", new { id=item.Id }, new { id = "add"})
```

JQuery

```
$(function() {
    $('#add').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).modal();
    });
});
```